# Disable swipe in tabbed activity (Android Studio)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-tablayout, android-tabbed-activity

i want to disable the swipe function in the tabbed activity. I tried some examples i found but it didn't worked or the code was completely different.
Here is my code:

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.example;

import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;


    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }




    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).

            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return FragmentOne.newInstance("a","b");
                case 1:
                    return FragmentTwo.newInstance("a","b");
                case 2:
                    return FragmentThree.newInstance("a","b");
                case 3:
                    return FragmentFour.newInstance("a","b");
                case 4:
                    return FragmentFive.newInstance("a","b");
                default:
                    return FragmentThree.newInstance("a","b");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "One";
                case 1:
                    return "Two";
                case 2:
                    return "Three";
                case 3:
                    return "Four";
                case 4:
                    return "Five";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }


    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {

        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";


        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
            textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
            return rootView;
        }
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity"
    android:background="#1d2935">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:src="@mipmap/icon_plus_normal"
        app:backgroundTint="#1d2935" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: create custom view pager and modify few method [http://www.unknownerror.org/opensource/thebird/Swipe/q/stackoverflow/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s](http://www.unknownerror.org/opensource/thebird/Swipe/q/stackoverflow/9650265/how-do-disable-paging-by-swiping-with-finger-in-viewpager-but-still-be-able-to-s)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to create Custom **ViewPager** Class this way .

```
public class CustomViewPager extends ViewPager {
private boolean swipeable = false;

public CustomViewPager(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomViewPager(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

// Call this method in your motion events when you want to disable or enable
// It should work as desired.
public void setSwipeable(boolean swipeable) {
    this.swipeable = swipeable;
}

@Override
public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent arg0) {
    return (this.swipeable) ? super.onInterceptTouchEvent(arg0) : false;
}
```

Now

```
    CustomViewPager ViewPagerObj = (CustomViewPager)findViewById(R.id.container);
    ViewPagerObj.setSwipeable(false);
```

You should add this in your XML

```
 <Your_packagename.CustomViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer does not work for me. Beginners can just use this kotlin file instead of the accepted answer java file.

```
class CustomViewPager: ViewPager {
    private var swipeable = false
    constructor(context: Context) : super(context) 
    constructor(context:Context, attrs: AttributeSet) : super(context, attrs) 
    fun setSwipeable(swipeable:Boolean) {
        this.swipeable = swipeable
    }
    override fun onInterceptTouchEvent(arg0: MotionEvent):Boolean {
        return if ((this.swipeable)) super.onInterceptTouchEvent(arg0) else false
    }

    override fun onTouchEvent(event:MotionEvent):Boolean {
        return if (this.swipeable) super.onTouchEvent(event) else false
    }


}
```